# Different Answers by removing a printf statement

Tags: c

This is the link to the question on UVa online judge.
https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=29&page=show_problem&problem=1078

My C code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

double avg(double * arr,int students)
{

    int i;
    double average=0;

    for(i=0;i<students;i++){
        average=average+(*(arr+i));
    }

    average=average/students;

    int temp=average*100;

    average=temp/100.0;

    return average;
}


double mon(double * arr,int students,double average)
{
    int i;
    double count=0;

    for(i=0;i<students;i++){

        if(*(arr+i)<average){
            double temp=average-*(arr+i);

            int a=temp*100;

            temp=a/100.0;

            count=count+temp;
        }
    }

    return count;
}


int main(void)
{
    // your code goes here
    int students;

    scanf("%d",&students);

    while(students!=0){

        double arr[students];
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<students;i++){
            scanf("%lf",&arr[i]);

        }

        double average=avg(arr,students);

        //printf("%lf\n",average);

        double money=mon(arr,students,average);

        printf("$%.2lf\n",money);

        scanf("%d",&students);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

One of the input and outputs are
Input
3
0.01
0.03
0.03
0

Output
$0.01

**My output is 
 $0.00.**

However if I **uncomment the line printf("%lf",average);**
The Output is as follows
0.02 //This is the average
$0.01

I am running the code on ideone.com

Please explain why is this happening.

Comment: Strange, locally works fine

Comment: writing `(*(arr+i))` instead of `arr[i]` doesn't make you look cooler :)

Comment: What is the output @maskacovnik

Comment: My output is $0.01 with comment

Comment: using the printf statement in the function mon before returning also prints the output as 0.01

Comment: It's possible this is some kind of rounding issue - maybe your computer is computing the output as `0.00999999` or something. If so, you might want to do all your math with integer cents (assuming the problem lets you do this).

Comment: ...but `printf` does in fact round the output, so that can't be it. I also get `$0.01` as output, strangely...

Comment: Can it be due to different complier versions.?

Comment: @AdityaSharma: `$0.01` on my machine, [`$0.00` on IDEOne](http://ideone.com/r5cHK1). I don't yet see any UB stuff here, but something is clearly fishy...

Comment: Multiplying and dividing by 100 in sequence is the wrong way to do whatever it is that you want to do. Look at floor() or ceil() if you want to round floating point numbers.

Comment: I don't see any reason why your code with the comment should produce different output than your code without the comment does.  Such an outcome hinges on undefined or unfavorable implementation-defined behavior, but I do not see anything in your code that would fall in that category.

Comment: I want to round it till 2 decimal places @Jeff.And then do arithmetic.

Comment: Is it possible this is a compiler bug? I see the correct output with gcc 4.3.2: http://ideone.com/6TKEhL

Comment: "Can it be due to different complier versions?"  Inasmuch as the behavior at ideaone appears to be buggy, I would say yes, it could be due to a different compiler version.

Comment: Do note, by the way, that variable-length arrays are a C99 feature, though GCC recognizes them by default in C90 mode, too.  Your code uses them acceptably, but it does tread in an area that's a bit near the edge with the way it updates the value of the length expression within the scope of the VLA, and thereby gives the VLA a different length at each iteration.  These are not programming errors, but they *are* places where a compiler bug might lodge.

Answer (score 8):

I believe I've found the culprit and a reasonable explanation.

On x86 processors, the FPU operates internally with *extended precision*, which is an 80-bit format. All of the floating point instructions operate with this precision. If a `double` is actually required, the compiler will generate code to convert the extended precision value down to a double precision value. Crucially, the commented-out `printf` forces such a conversion because the FPU registers must be saved and restored across that function call, and they will be saved as `double`s (note that `avg` and `mon` are both inlined so no save/restore happens there).

In fact, instead of `printf` we can use the line `static double dummy = average;` to force the `double` conversion to occur, which also causes the bug to disappear: http://ideone.com/a1wadn

Your value of `average` is close to but not exactly `0.02` because of floating-point inaccuracies. When I do all the calculations explicitly with `long double`, and I print out the value of `average`, it is the following:

```
long double: 0.01999999999999999999959342418532
double: 0.02000000000000000041633363423443
```

Now you can see the problem. When you add the `printf`, `average` is forced to a `double` which pushes it above 0.02. But, without the `printf`, `average` will be a little less than 0.02 in its native extended precision format.

When you do `int a=temp*100;` the bug appears. Without the conversion, this makes `a = 1`. With the conversion, this makes `a = 2`.

To fix this, simply use `int a=round(temp*100);` - all your weird errors should vanish.

---

Of note, this bug is *extremely* sensitive to changes in the code. Anything that causes the registers to be saved (such as a `printf` pretty much anywhere) will actually cause the bug to vanish. Hence, this is an extremely good example of a *heisenbug*: a bug that vanishes when you try to investigate it.

Comment: Hmmm, I was also concerned about the 0.0199999... being just a tiny little bit below 0.02. But shouldn't the result being specified by the IEEE/ISO rules for floating-point operations? And therefore should differences only arise if using the -ffast-math flag (or similar)?

Comment: `(int)(0.019999 * 100)` is always 1. And, we don't know if IDEOne is using `-ffast-math` or not (I cannot seem to find their compiler flags). I also know that floating-point operations only have to be accurate to various fractions of an ulp, but that is still enough error that the result could be above/below 0.02 without affecting that guarantee.

Comment: Of course, if IDEOne applies unsafe optimizations, everything is possible in this numerically unstable situation. But otherwise, I'd expect the results to be deterministic. Do you have references for the claim that the floating-point operations aren't fully defined? At least the IEEE 754 standard demands deterministic behavior for the operations used here.

Comment: I was trying to convert double to two decimal places.For example 9,005 to 9,00 . Can you tell me how to do it

Comment: `printf` is a big chunk of code ... can you find a simpler one-liner to insert that makes this (mis)behave in the same way?

Comment: Yeah, `static volatile double dummy = average` does the same thing.

Comment: @mastov: The standard doesn't demand *deterministic* behaviour, it demands *bounded error* behaviour. This is a critical distinction. Calculation results are allowed to deviate from the true mathematical results by a certain amount, usually specified in multiples of the units-in-last-place (ulp). Different implementations can use different algorithms so long as they are within this error bound, and floating point answers may actually vary across different systems.

Comment: @AdityaSharma: Using `round(x*100)/100.0` will work. However, you might be better off doing all your math on the cents (multiplying everything by 100). You can use this trick to print a dollar value from an integral number of cents: `printf("%d.%02d", cents/100, cents%100);`

Comment: @Jongware: I added the necessary `static double dummy = average;` line to the answer.

Comment: @nneonneo: That's not how IEEE 754 defines it, it requires the results to be the closest representable value to the mathematically exact result. And I was under the impression that C99 mandates IEEE 754. Where am I wrong?

Comment: It is not correct that the compiler will use 80-bit by default. It actually uses either 64-bit (FPU or SSE) on all platform I have seen.

Comment: I think that the result is more accurate with `long double` than with `double`, and that there's some compounding of error that must occur with a conversion and a conversion back to extended precision. That error is going to be less than 1/2 ulp for sure, but it may still be enough (once casted back to extended precision) that it leads to the error.

Comment: @Dani: If it uses x87 FPU, then it uses 80-bit values because that's what the FPU uses *internally*. Whenever the compiler transfers numbers between the FPU register stack and regular registers, it converts them with `fst`/`fld`.

Comment: @mastov: C99 does not mandate IEEE754. It says: "An implementation that defines `__STDC_IEC_559__` shall conform to the specifications in this annex. [which is basically IEEE754]".

Answer (score 2):

[@nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30821386/2410359) well answered most of the issue: Slightly variant compilations result in slightly different floating-point code that result in *nearly* the same `double` answer, except one answer is just below 2.0 and the the other at or just about 2.0.

Like to add about the importance on not using conversion to `int` for floating point rounding.

Code like `double temp; ... int a=temp*100;` accentuate this difference resulting in `a` with a value of 1 or 2 as conversion to `int` is effective "truncate toward zero" - drop the fraction.

Rather than round to near 0.01 with code like:

```
double temp;
...
int a = temp*100;  // Problem is here
temp = a/100.0;
```

Do not use `int` at all.  Use

```
double temp;
...
temp = round(temp*100.0)/100.0;
```

Not only does this provide more consistent answers (as `temp` is unlikely to have values near a [half-cent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_cent_(United_States_coin))), it also allows `temp` values outside the `int` range.  `temp = 1e13; int a = temp/100;` certainly results in undefined behavior.

> Do not use conversion to `int` to round floating-point numbers: use `round()`

`roundf()`, `roundl()`, `floor()`, `ceil()`, etc. may also be useful. [@jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189128/jeff)

Answer (score -4):

You're dividing a double by an integer, which is integer division. In this case it will give a value of 0.

If you cast student to a double it should give you proper output.

```
average=average/(double)students;
```

There might be other locations this is needed depending on your arithmetic.

Comment: What? `double/int` is double division. I don't know what you're on about.

Comment: But why does removing printf or adding it changes my answer

Comment: Yes i think double/int is a double division

Comment: @AdityaSharma It is indeed, and this answer is both incorrect and irrelevant to your question. If I changed anything in your code I would remove all the `100`x and go strictly with `double`, using `floor` or `ceil` for whatever rounding you think you need.